# How serious is the issue of vast quantities of methane release from an ice-free Arctic?

Tags: climate-change, greenhouse-gases, sea-ice, methane, arctic

A bunch of climate scientists claim that [humans will go extinct by 2026](http://arctic-news.blogspot.com/p/extinction.html), when humanity crosses the major tipping point known as "[Arctic Blue Ocean Event (BOE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctic_sea_ice_decline#Implications)".

According to the climate scientists at [Arctic News blog](https://arctic-news.blogspot.com); due to [BOE](https://glennfay.medium.com/the-blue-ocean-event-will-be-a-tipping-point-for-our-climate-42c05898862c) several positive feedback loop will kick in. One of the major positive feedback loop would be large amount of methane released from [Siberian permafrost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctic_methane_emissions). (Please refer: -  [Clathrate gun hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clathrate_gun_hypothesis)).

Since I am not a climate scientist, I would like to ask the experts in the field of climatology, whether such reports are accurate or not. According to the aforementioned blog the global average temperature will rise up by 18 degree Celsius!

Is it too late to stop climate change? Are there any solution to prevent Arctic ice from melting completely?

Comment: Notably the Arctic News blog referenced here is not produced by climate scientists, but by an anonymous blogger who seems to have added the top range of every possible forcing referenced in papers to forecast an 18C rise in temperature by 2026. The blogger also forecast an ice-free arctic by 2019, which didn't happen.

Comment: @jeffronicus Please see this link.

http://arctic-news.blogspot.com/p/about.html

The blog claims that a number of scientist contribute to the blog, some of them I believe are quite renowned.

Comment: But that's not actually a list of contributors, just people he mentions. As stated on that page: "Note that clicking on above names will produce both posts written be the respective contributor as well as posts that *may merely mention the name of a specific contributor.*" The fact that he's pretending Peter Wadhams is a contributor when all the author has done is post YouTube videos of Wadhams and comment on them should give you a sense of the author's credibility.